# Where to add App Icon for iPad PRO

Tags: xcode, ipad, icons, asset-catalog

I've read on this site to do the following:

**Create a 167x167 icon file. The guidelines on icons state clearly that file names for icons are not relevant, so I named it "Icon-83.5@2x.png".**

**Add the file to the project, and add the file name to your app's plist array CFBundleIconFiles~ipad.**

I created an images asset file but there was nothing in it. I don't know if the above way to do it is the official way Apple states to do it or not because I can't find any documentation regarding iPad PRO App Icon in Apple developer documents.

I'm using Xcode 7.1, i've read nothing changed for iPad PRO App Icon in Xcode 7.1.1. So how do I add an App Icon for iPad PRO? Or do I just let the iPad Air App Icon scale into iPad Pro App Icon?